# how do you add sound when you click a button in xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, audio, button

I want to code a button to make a sound when you tap it. If I were to have a sound file like test.ogg or test.wav how could I pull that off? I'm somewhat new to xml so be kinda descriptive. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/531/buttons-and-sounds-android-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:onClick="sendMessage"`, and make a function in your activity like this:

```
/** Called when the user touches the button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Play your sound
}
```

Whenever the user click your button, it will trigger this function and, therefore, play your sound.

Comment: Next time try to read a little, like: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html - I even forgot to change the function name...

You're welcome :D.

Comment: Yeah. I just get mad when i cant find what I want within a few minutes. :P

Comment: one more thing, where do you add the sound file code and how do you code it? i used a different method and it keeps screwing up

Answer (score 1):

You can use standart mechanic for `View` - set sound resource with method [playSoundEffect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#playSoundEffect%28int%29).

And you need set [setSoundEffectsEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSoundEffectsEnabled%28boolean%29) programatically or in xml of your view [android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3asoundEffectsEnabled).